Install Ubuntu on a drive with Ubuntu and Windows
I'm not a great expert, my apologies.
Several partitions on my hard drive, one with Ubuntu and another for Windows. While upgrading from Ubuntu 22 to 24 the power went out. Now I can't boot Ubuntu, the process stops. Last messages:
[FAILED] Failed to start Authorization Manager.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Modem Manager.
[FAILED] Failes to start Dispatcher Daemon for systemd-network.

In safe mode I can get the console, but not fix the problem because apt tries to access the Internet. I have read that the easiest thing is reinstalling from scratch. I've tried but I end up with three options:

“Install Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu 24.0.1.LTS. You'll be able to
choose the system at each boot”
“Erase disk and install Ubuntu”
“Manual installation”

If I choose 1, I get "Sorry, we're not sure what the error is" Last messages are:
[datetime] ubuntu subiquity_event_3751 [3751]:
[datetime] ubuntu subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:

With option 2 I would lose the Windows partition
And with option 3 I would also lose Windows, because it forces me to delete the current partitions
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Wait, what? Why does option 3 force you to delete the current partitions? Are you 100% sure it does? There should be a manual partitioning option there.

Actually I dont knopw, but i've to delete at least one partition to ensure there is enough space. It appears in https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/04/install-ubuntu-24-04-desktop/

Well yes, but you would delete the existing / partition of your installed Ubuntu system. You wouldn't touch the Windows one.

Installation fails when reinstalling. I've got varios partitions
sda1 system boot, sda2 extended composed of sd5 Linux/ and sd6 Linux swap, sda3 Windows, sda4 Windows recovery. If i delete sda6, sda5 and sda2, create another to mount /, crash with error report, StackTrace "Exception Exceeded number of available partitions". I have to revert. The same just deleting sda5 and sda6. Deleting without creating another, and selecting sda2 as boot device, another Exception indicating that it already is boot device (although this is not reflected in Ubuntu installer)

I can't really help without knowing your partition set up. But if you delete the extended partition sda2, you can't keep any of the partitions it contains (sda5, sda6, sda3 or sda4). If you deleted sda2 and that was the logical extended partition containing the others, you lost the others. If you add your partitioning setup to the question, we might be able to help more.

In my previous comment I wanted to say that sda2 contains sda5 and sda6. Only those

Maybe your safe mode did not configure internet connection properly?
Everything can be fix using CLI, if you know what to do. Heck, even able to login via CLI is already consider running Linux the OS.
If you want to re-install, better go to live session, open gparted, format the current Linux partition. During installation process, chose "Something else" option. After that assign the grub, uefi  and root (/) partition correctly. Manual option or "Something else" should not force you to format windows or data partition. That's why use live session, prepare everything first before entering installation mode.
If you want an adventure, go back to CLI. Check Ubuntu version via one of this command.
lsb_release -a
cat /etc/lsb-release
cat /etc/os-release
cat /etc/issue
hostnamectl

In safe mode, option to enable network should be available.
https://pimylifeup.com/ubuntu-recovery-mode/
Use ip -a to check network status. If you got internet or able to mount Ubuntu 24.02 .iso, I guess you can just run sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop.
My answer maybe not helping you out, I just want to contribute to Ubuntu forum.

Thanks. The ideal solution would be to access the network from recovery mode. But I don't know how to do it, and the network option in the recovery menu doesn't work. And all the commands in CLI indicate that version is already Ubuntu 24

Last time I did setup network via CLI in on Ubuntu server. I follow this guideline. (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks). Mount Xubuntu .ISO and install XFCE also faster  (https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html). Add to sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list. If you want the exact command, I can help pin point it where it is inside link above.

Not an answer, I Know, but I finally decided remove all partitions and install from scratch. I think this is easier than troubleshooting with the installer (initial question) or set up network (the incoherent state of the installation cause problems like missing libraries in instructions from https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks)
